# Advanced search in Outlook 2007 - can I turn on Search subfolders by default?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

When I do an Advanced Search (CTRL-SHIFT-F) in Outlook 2007, the Search subfolders option is always off by default.
I have to click the Browse button and enable the checkbox at the bottom of the dialog every time.

In Outlook 2002, it remembered the setting.

Can Outlook 2007 be made to remember this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Outlook 2007 be made to remember
>   this setting?

in a word, no.

Comment: Same in Outlook 2010 - pain in the...